# How to insert gridview data into database as a list(Multiple rows) WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have tried to send data as a string and it is working correctly. but now i want to insert all gridview data as a list into database. Code is here

```
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]

    string InsertCustomerDetails(UserDetails userInfo);


    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]

    List<CustomerTable> GetCustomers();
}


public class UserDetails
{

    string Name = string.Empty;    
    string City = string.Empty;
    [DataMember]
    public string name
    {

        get { return Name; }

        set { Name = value; }

    }
    [DataMember]
    public string city
    {

        get { return City; }

        set { City = value; }

    }



public class Service1 : IService1
{




  public string InsertCustomerDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
    {
        using(DataContext db=new DataContext())
        {
            CustomerTable customer = new CustomerTable();
            customer.Name = userInfo.name;
            customer.City = userInfo.city;
              db.CustomerTables.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return "name=  " + userInfo.name + "     city=  " + userInfo.city;
    }
}
```

}

WEB Form Code

```
  protected void ButtonADD_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++) {
            UserDetails info = new UserDetails();
            info.name = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
            info.city = GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
            obj.InsertCustomerDetails(info);
    } }
```

Comment: What went wrong with your loop?

Comment: Please edit your code and indent it correctly if you want that collaborators help you. There are some mistakes with brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Iservice1 class use this

```
     public List<CustomerTable> InsertCustomerDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
    {
        using(DataContext db=new DataContext())
        {
            CustomerTable customer = new CustomerTable();
            customer.Name = userInfo.name;
            customer.City = userInfo.city;
              db.CustomerTables.Add(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return db.CustomerTables.ToList();
        }
```

Use this in interface. Make setter getters in class UserDetails

```
   [OperationContract]

    List<CustomerTable> InsertCustomerDetails(UserDetails userInfo);
```

I Have done this. Just facing problem in Web Form. Any Help will be appriciated. I want to send dqata as list into database